# Message: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: context.Contact

Tags: xdb, sitecore-api

I am working on Sitecore 8.2 version.  I am getting an exception in production environment log file. I am not able to replicate same issue in my local neither able to figure out why this issue is occurring though this seems related to xDB.

```
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: context.Contact
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.MarketingAutomation.AutomationExtensions.CreateAutomationStateManager(Session context)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.ContactAutomationEvents.Run(Session session, PageEventItem pageEventDefinitionItem)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.RegisterPageEvent.RegisterPageEventPipeline.Run(RegisterPageEventArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.PageContext.Register(PageEventItem pageEventItem, PageEventData pageData)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.PageContext.Register(PageEventData pageData)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Extensions.ErrorExtensions.RegisterError(IPageContext page, String text, String dataKey, String data)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.TrackingUtilities.ProcessAnalyticsLog(CurrentInteraction interaction, AnalyticsLogger logger)
```

Can someone suggest me why this issue is occurring?

Comment: Do you possibly have contacts enrolled in automation plans that don't exist in xDB?

Comment: ok,Need to check. Thnx :)